# How do I change the variable from a NoneType to a Float in a lambda function?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda, nonetype, sqrt

I have been trying to create a square root function using the code from a [website](https://www.simplifiedpython.net/python-calculator/) which explains how to make a tkinter calculator. The complete code from the program should be near the middle of the website.

What I attempted to do is to reuse the code from the equals sign in order to create a square root button that would square root whatever is entered into the entry box. I place the code in the `def __init__(self):` along with the rest of the code. Here is the code I added to the program:

```
sqButton = iCalc(self, TOP)
    for iEquals in "√":
        btniEquals = button(sqButton, LEFT, iEquals)
        btniEquals.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', lambda e, s=self,
                            storeObj=display: math.sqrt(s.calc(storeObj)))
```

In trying to do this I get an error.

```
line 50, in <lambda> storeObj=display: math.sqrt(s.calc(storeObj)))             
TypeError: must be real number, not NoneType
```

I go to the problem source which is the code above. Attempting to change "lambda" would give me a syntax error so I'm not sure what I should do to change it so that it functions as expected. As far as I can tell, the "e" after the function gives me the NoneType which stops the code from working, I tried to surround `s.calc(storeObj)` in float but it doesn't remove the error, and I have added an import math at the top of the program so the math.sqrt should work. I'm not a novice at this so I don't exactly know what I need to change so it works.

Comment: You need to check what is returned by `s.calc(storeObj)`.  From the website link, it returns None.

Comment: The article you linked to has a lot of bad practices in the code. It's not a good article to learn from.

Comment: My advice: don't use a complex lambda. Have the button call a proper function. That will make the code much easier to understand and much easier to debug.

Answer (score -1):

You can write lambda function as mentioned below

```
func = lambda e: 0.0 if e == None else e
print(func(None))
print(func(1))
```

Result

```
0.0
1
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect.  No comma after None.  Also OP issue is not how to use lambda.